# In multiple regression, how to interpret multiple percentage covariates?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, percentage

I have the continuous variable Y and the predictors Pct_less10, Pct_10to20, and Pct_21plus.

NOTE: The predictors are basically percentage of people under age category and they add up to 1. So my observation level is Y at the monthly level, and I have covariates as Percentage of people less than 10 years old, percentage of people between 10 and 20 (excluding 10), and percentage of people from 21 or more. The percentages are between 0 and 1.

1. Assuming Y is also a proportion, I have the model:

   $$Y= \beta_0 +\beta_1{\rm Pct.10to20}+\beta_2{\rm Pct.21plus}+\beta_3X+ \epsilon$$ 
   where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

   The "base" category is Pct.less.than.10. How do I read the coefficients for this kind of regression? Also, in case the data suggest that ONLY Pct.21plus is important in the model, and I drop the first covariate would that change the interpretation of $\beta_2$ which is the coefficient for Pct.21.plus?